# Inducing WebDriverWait for specific elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, wait

This question is a follow up to my previous question ([Inconsistency in scraping through <div>'s in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540289/inconsistency-in-scraping-through-divs-in-selenium)). I'm working on scraping all of the Air Jordan Data off of grailed.com (https://www.grailed.com/designers/jordan-brand/hi-top-sneakers). I am storing the size, model, url, and image url in an object. I currently have a program that scrolls through the entire feed and fetches all of this. Everything works except finding the image url. The image URL seems to require inducing an explicit wait, which @KunduK suggested. I'm trying to implement his solution so that I can pull each image in my for loop:

```
 while True and len(sneakers) < sneaker_count:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Get sneakers currently on page and add to sneakers list
    feed = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('feed-item')
    images = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
      EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".feed-item .listing-cover-photo>img")))
    for item in feed:
      ...
```

Currently the code fetches the image in a group at once. I am trying to fetch the image during the "for item in feed" block. I want something like `images = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_elements_located((By.SOME SELECTOR", ???)))` but I really don't know how to find these using the 'item' element. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape the image url from each image using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.grailed.com/designers/jordan-brand/hi-top-sneakers')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.product-card-container")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.grailed.com/designers/jordan-brand/hi-top-sneakers')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='product-card-container']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.grailed.com/products/57773-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-court-purple', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/57803-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-obsidian', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/57759-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-2017-royal', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/57760-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-2018-shadow', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/59036-jordan-brand-air-jordan-4-retro-og-2019-bred', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/115772-jordan-brand-jordan-1-retro-high-og-pine-green', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/57817-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-shattered-backboard-3-0', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/61668-jordan-brand-travis-scott-travis-scott-x-air-jordan-4-retro-cactus-jack', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/114979-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-unc-to-chi', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/97122-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-fearless', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/97133-jordan-brand-air-jordan-11-bred-2019', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/61725-jordan-brand-air-jordan-4-retro-cool-grey', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/57762-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-banned-2016-banned-bred', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/87098-jordan-brand-travis-scott-travis-scott-x-air-jordan-6-retro-olive', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/57768-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-bred-toe', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/112831-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-royal-toe', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/111383-jordan-brand-air-jordan-4-retro-black-cat-2020', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/58136-jordan-brand-travis-scott-travis-scott-x-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-mocha', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/57825-jordan-brand-air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-turbo-green', 'https://www.grailed.com/products/111377-jordan-brand-off-white-air-jordan-5-retro-sp-muslin']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: For sure, what I'm looking for is a solution that happens within my for loop, for example. after ```for item in feed: img = item.get_attribute("src") ``` but somehow use WebDriverWait in this statement. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: It was helpful (upvote given), but I'm still stuck on the same issue. I used your xpath strategy as well as implementing some other stuff, it would be excellent if you could help out - see my latest question for specifics.